# ! Missing \endcsname error... I can't find the problem

Tags: cross-referencing

I can not compile my tex file into pdf using winedit 9. This is my issue. I have attached the tex file as well. Please any help would be appreciated in fixing this problem. The issue is apparently within my auxiliary file.

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  
>                      \color@endgroup  l.3 \newlabel{\color@endgroup }{{1}{1}{}{}{}}

Update: By experimenting I found that I can bypass the "! Missing" problem by pressing Enter to ignore it. The only issue I have now is that the compilation ignores the opening of my paper (ie Title) .

Whenever I input the following, it will NEVER be compiled onto my document.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4}
%\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
%\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\title{Assessment of High Sensitivity MEMS Strain Sensor}
\author{Vernon D. Dutch}
\email[]{vdutch01@gmail.com}
\affiliation{Southern University \& AM College}
\address{801 Harding Blvd, Baton Rouge,LA }


\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
A sensor is a device that detects events that occur within a physical environment (like light, heat, motion, moisture, pressure, and more), and responds with certain output, usually as the electrical, mechanical or optical signal. A typical mercury thermometer is a common sensor. It detects temperature and reacts with a measurable expansion of liquid. Almost omnipresent, sensors are found in everyday applications like touch-sensitive elevator buttons and even experimental sensors that are used in medicine and robotics.  Also, the long decay length of charge carriers at room temperature will also be explained. The validity of the decay length in MOSFET structures will be discussed in detail. The extended environmental contribution of these devices will also be focused upon.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

I am trying so if more feedback needed please comment

Comment: You don't just attach it. The polite and helpful thing to do is to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  It is helpful to you because it promotes better answers more quickly, and it is helpful to others because they don't need to construct a file that demonstrates the problem (working backwards from the error, no less).  When you have your MWE, edit the question to include it.

Comment: You should make a small complete document that generates that error (it should only need to be a few lines). You apparently have something invalid in the argument to `\label` but it is hard to guess what from your fragment.

Comment: This is the `.aux` file, not very useful in this case

Comment: Add `\maketitle` after `\end{abstract}`.

Comment: Sorry, but it compiles for me. Remove the `.aux` file manually and retry. Note that `\address` is interpreted as `\affiliation` by `revtex4-1`. Just continue in the argument to `\affiliation`, using ``\\`` for breaking.